# Segmentation fault while system function call

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, pthreads, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to find the cause of a segmentation fault error which is happening when I try to generate Signal (^C) when System function is involved.

Also I am trying to understand why I see only one print `Thread1 cancelled` and not 3 prints for all three threads? *[`Corrected the code for this point`]*

Below is the code for the testapp.c. This is a kind of stress test app I have made to test [my utility program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980466/wait-until-the-previous-instance-of-process-finish). The utility program is not the actual program which I am using but to demonstrate the use of semaphore used in it. It is executing my utility program using `system()` function.

Source code and output is listed below,

```
/*******  testapp.c  *****************/
/* gcc testapp.c -o testapp -pthread */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SLEEP1  250
#define SLEEP2  250
#define SLEEP3  250
pthread_t   thread1;
pthread_t   thread2;
pthread_t   thread3;
static volatile sig_atomic_t isRunning = 1;

void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    int rc = 0;
    switch (signal)
    {
        case SIGINT:
        case SIGTERM:
        case SIGQUIT:
            printf("Signal generated, cancelling threads...");
            // Graceful shutdown
            //isRunning = 0; //commented to see the segmentation fault issue
            rc = pthread_cancel(thread1);
            if(rc != 0){
                printf("signal_handler:pthread_cancel-1 failed - %d (%m)\n", errno);
            }
            printf("Thread1 cancelled\n");
            rc = pthread_cancel(thread2);
            if(rc != 0){
                printf("signal_handler:pthread_cancel-2 failed - %d (%m)\n", errno);
            }
            printf("Thread2 cancelled\n");
            rc = pthread_cancel(thread3);
            if(rc != 0){
                printf("signal_handler:pthread_cancel-3 failed - %d (%m)\n", errno);
            }
            printf("Thread3 cancelled\n");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void* thread1_worker(void* data)
{
    struct timeval timeout;
    int ret = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Requesting cmd1\n");
        ret = system("util -c:cmd1 -v 2>> /tmp/stderr.log");

        timeout.tv_sec  = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = SLEEP1 * 1000;  //milliseconds
        ret = select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    }while(isRunning);

    printf("Exiting thread1...");
    pthread_exit((void*)0);
}

void* thread2_worker(void* data)
{
    struct timeval timeout;
    int ret = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Requesting cmd2\n");
        ret = system("util -c:cmd2 -v 2>> /tmp/stderr.log");

        timeout.tv_sec  = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = SLEEP2 * 1000;  //milliseconds
        int ret = select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    }while(isRunning);

    printf("Exiting thread2...");
    pthread_exit((void*)0);
}

void* thread3_worker(void* data)
{
    struct timeval timeout;
    int ret = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Requesting cmd3\n");
        ret = system("util -c:cmd3 -v 2>> /tmp/stderr.log");

        timeout.tv_sec  = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = SLEEP3 * 1000;  //milliseconds
        int ret = select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    }while(isRunning);

    printf("Exiting thread3...");
    pthread_exit((void*)0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGQUIT, signal_handler);

    printf("Starting threads...\n");
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread1_worker, (void*) NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, thread2_worker, (void*) NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, thread3_worker, (void*) NULL);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is below, The prints in the square brackets is the actual output of the program and not the util program above,

```
root@mydevice:~$ testapp 
Starting threads...
Requesting cmd1
Requesting cmd2
Requesting cmd3
cmd2:[05 05]
cmd1:[0]
cmd3:[00 00 00 00 00 ]
Requesting cmd2
Requesting cmd1
cmd2:[05 05]
Requesting cmd3
cmd1:[1]
cmd3:[00 00 00 00 00 ]
Requesting cmd2
Requesting cmd1
cmd2:[05 05]
Requesting cmd3
cmd1:[2]
cmd3:[00 00 00 00 00 ]
Requesting cmd2
Requesting cmd1
cmd2:[05 05]
Requesting cmd3
cmd1:[3]
cmd3:[00 00 00 00 00 ]
Requesting cmd2
Requesting cmd1
cmd2:[05 05]
Requesting cmd3
^Ccmd1:[4]
sh: line 1:   964 Segmentation fault      util -c:cmd3 -v 2>> /tmp/stderr.log
Requesting cmd2
cmd2:[05 05]
Requesting cmd1
Requesting cmd3
cmd1:[5]
cmd3:[00 00 00 00 00 ]
Requesting cmd2
cmd2:[05 05]
Requesting cmd1
Requesting cmd3
cmd3:[00 00 00 00 00 ]
Requesting cmd2
cmd1:[84213760]
Requesting cmd3
^Ccmd2:[00 00]  -----------------------------------------------> Signal
cmd3:[00 00 00 00 00 ]
Requesting cmd1
cmd1:[7]
Requesting cmd2
Requesting cmd3
cmd2:[05 05]
cmd3:[00 00 00 00 00 ]
Requesting cmd1
cmd1:[8]
^CSignal generated, cancelling threads...Thread1 cancelled ---->Signal
Segmentation fault
root@mydevice:~$
```

Comment: OT: `(void*)0` is expected to be the same as `NULL`.

Comment: @alk: Thanks for your input, Its already there but I wanted to rule out any un-expected problem like segmentation fault. This may be in my util program also.

Comment: OT^2: Thou shalt not printf from signal handlers.

Comment: @OP Do a [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and look for the list of signal safe functions.

Comment: the posted code does NOT cleanly compile.  So your first step is to correct all the messages output by the compiler.  As a hint: in the `main()` function, the `argc` and `argv` parameters are not used, so the signature for `main()` should be: `int main( void )`.   for other functions: if a parameter is not used, then the first statement in the body of the function should be something similar to: `(void)data;`   There are unused variables.  There are variables set but not used like `ret`.

Comment: when calling system functions, like `pthread_create()`, always check the returned value to assure the function was successful

Comment: DO NOT call `printf()` from inside a signal handler However, `write()` is acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correcting the code, per the comments results in:

```
/*******  testapp.c  *****************/
/* gcc testapp.c -o testapp -pthread */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SLEEP1  250
#define SLEEP2  250
#define SLEEP3  250

pthread_t   thread1;
pthread_t   thread2;
pthread_t   thread3;

static volatile sig_atomic_t isRunning = 1;

void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    int rc = 0;
    char buffer[1024];

    switch (signal)
    {
        case SIGINT:
        case SIGTERM:
        case SIGQUIT:
            write( 1, "Signal generated, cancelling threads...\n");
            // Graceful shutdown
            //isRunning = 0; //commented to see the segmentation fault issue
            rc = pthread_cancel(thread1);
            if( rc )
            {
                write(1, "signal_handler:pthread_cancel-1 failed\n" ):
            }

            write( 1, "Thread1 cancelled\n");


            rc = pthread_cancel(thread2);
            if( rc )
            {
                write( 1, "signal_handler:pthread_cancel-2 failed\n");
            }

            write( 1, "Thread2 cancelled\n");


            rc = pthread_cancel(thread3);
            if( rc )
            {
                write( 1, "signal_handler:pthread_cancel-3 failed\n");
            }

            "Thread3 cancelled\n");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    } // end switch
} // end function: signal_handler


void* thread1_worker(void* data)
{
    struct timeval timeout;
    int ret = 0;

    (void)data;

    do
    {
        printf("Requesting cmd1\n");
        ret = system("util -c:cmd1 -v 2>> /tmp/stderr.log");
        if( ret )
        {
            perror( "system-util result" );
        }

        timeout.tv_sec  = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = SLEEP1 * 1000;  //milliseconds
        select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    } while(isRunning);

    printf("Exiting thread1...\n");
    pthread_exit( NULL );
} // end function: thread1_worker


void* thread2_worker(void* data)
{
    struct timeval timeout;
    int ret = 0;

    (void)data;

    do
    {
        printf("Requesting cmd2\n");
        ret = system("util -c:cmd2 -v 2>> /tmp/stderr.log");
        if( ret )
        {
            perror( "system-util result" );
        }

        timeout.tv_sec  = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = SLEEP2 * 1000;  //milliseconds
        select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    }while(isRunning);

    printf("Exiting thread2...\n");
    pthread_exit((void*)0);
} // end function: thread2_worker


void* thread3_worker(void* data)
{
    struct timeval timeout;
    int ret = 0;

    (void)data;

    do
    {
        printf("Requesting cmd3\n");
        ret = system("util -c:cmd3 -v 2>> /tmp/stderr.log");
        if( ret )
        {
            perror( "system-util result" );
        }

        timeout.tv_sec  = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = SLEEP3 * 1000;  //milliseconds
        select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    }while(isRunning);

    printf("Exiting thread3...\n");
    pthread_exit((void*)0);
} // end function: thread3_worker


int main( void )
{
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGQUIT, signal_handler);

    printf("Starting threads...\n");
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread1_worker, (void*) NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, thread2_worker, (void*) NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, thread3_worker, (void*) NULL);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

when the code is run the following output is typical: (which continues to repeat with slight variations on the order of the statements:

```
system-util result: Success
system-util result: Success
system-util result: Success
Requesting cmd3
Requesting cmd2
Requesting cmd1
```

Then, since I have no `util` function the `/tmp/stderr.log` contains repeating statements of the following:

```
sh: 1: util: not found
sh: 1: util: not found
sh: 1: util: not found
sh: 1: util: not found
sh: 1: util: not found
sh: 1: util: not found
sh: 1: util: not found
sh: 1: util: not found
```

and, unless the `util` function is marked `executable` AND is in the same directory at this program, it will fail.

changing `util` to `./util` will work, if in the same directory without having to mark it as `executable`

The seg fault event is most likely from the `util` function rather than from the posted code.

further consideration should be given to calling the function: `signal()`, which per the man page is unreliable.  The man page strongly suggests using: `sigaction()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually `util` is stored on device `/usr/bin` so in the reference code above its like that. One point I want to mention here as you suspect the `util` might have the actual problem, `util` is also handling same number of signals as the `testapp`. I have shared the link to the `util` program in my original question.

Answer (score 3):

This was just a "typo" bug.

Change:

```
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread1_worker, (void*) NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread2_worker, (void*) NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread3_worker, (void*) NULL);
```

Into:

```
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread1_worker, (void*) NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, thread2_worker, (void*) NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, thread3_worker, (void*) NULL);
```

Comment: Ohhh. Nice catch. I was overlooking it and concentrating on signal handler. You resolved my one of two concern `Thread1 cancelled` raising this question. Thanks.